# Is it possible keep only value changes in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible to downsample older data using influxdb in a way that it only keeps change of values?

My example is the following:
I have a binary sensor sending data every 10 min, so naturally the consecutive values look something like this: 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0...

My goal is to keep this kind of raw data over a certain period of time using retention policies and downsample the data for longer storage. I want to delete all successive values with the same number so that I have only the datapoint with their timestamps when the value actually changed. The downsampled data should look like this: 0,1,0,1,0,1,0.... but with the correct timestamp when the event actually occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this isn't possible with InfluxDB, though the plan is to eventually support this kind of use case.

I would encourage you to open an [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/new) on the InfluxDB repo asking for this.

Comment: hi Michael.  Has something changed since 4 years?

Comment: Me too waiting.

Comment: Definitely would be a nice feature. if it could work for values and tags it would be even better.